# Suggestioned upgrades for a old Dell Studio XPS 8100

Tags: processor, motherboard, memory

[image: M,y specs]

I have been meaning to upgrade my desktop though i am not sure what would be best. Though admittedly i have not kept up to date with hardware so i am completely green in regards to where my specs should be. Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

I am not looking to upgrade my desktop to the highest quality or anything near it, i am trying to give it a modest upgrade to catch up with what's out now.

My uses are gaming; though this is at medium to high settings only. I am experiencing lag with my daily use and believe i may need to upgrade my ram.

I am experiencing them when i play dota 2 or league of legends while having my browser open, the number of tabs open seems not to matter much more do that i have the browser open. I also get them when i load the computer up and use it for my work related programs such as Microsoft powerbi. Though the whole pc seems to be slow now regardless of what i do. I am currently ruining windows 7 home premium. And my performance usually has my physical memory at 60% or above, my cpu seems to vary from 50 to 20 depending on what i am doing. I may need to scrutinize it more. My budget is around $700.

Comment: Can you tell us _where_ you are experiencing the bottlenecks? What games do you play? About how many browser tabs do you have open at any one time? What is your budget for upgrades? What does the performance tab of Task Manager look like? What OS are you running? The more information about your system, how you use it, and what the problem areas you have, the better our answers will be.

Comment: With that budget, I would look into getting 16GB of RAM and an SSD. The SSD will speed up loading times and the RAM will allow you to have more applications and browser tabs open.

Comment: @Cfinley do you have any suggestions of which type of RAM i should get or any particular brands or models for both items?

Comment: You need DDR3 and I would look at 4X4GB and 2X8GB sets to compare the prices. I personally like G-Skill, but I need to make sure what is compatible with your motherboard before I recommend anything.

Comment: @Cfinley its a stock dell motherboard from about 7+ years ago